# Selenium issue with form filling

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fill a form with selenium, from this website https://www.kartingbowling.com/vannes/page-comite-d-entreprise-22.html

here is the code :

```
code = 1010

bouton = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ticketce"]')
bouton.click()
time.sleep(2)

form = web.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/form/input[1]')
form.click()
form.send_keys(str(code))
```

it firsts clicks on "testez la validité de votre ticket CE"
then I want to fill the small box and click "verifier"

however, when I try it I get this exception at line 5 :

```
"selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/form/input[1]"}"
```

anybody knows how to fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this exception

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/form/input[1]"}
```

cause element is in iframe and you have not switched to it, and trying to access it.

Please switch to **iframe** first and then you can access the element.

```
code = "1010"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.kartingbowling.com/vannes/page-comite-d-entreprise-22.html")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#ticketce"))).click()

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.fancybox-iframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#code"))).send_keys(code)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#btn"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```